# Unchecking checkboxes not of a certain class

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to work with a multi-select set of checkboxes, but one of the options can be "N/A". If this is checked, I want all others (not having a class of input-na) unchecked. Also, if a non-NA checkbox is checked, I want the NA checkbox unchecked.

I've tried the following, but nothing is happening to the other checkboxes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox].input-na").change(function (event) {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $('input[type=checkbox]').not('.input-na').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });

    $("input[type=checkbox]").not(".input-na").change(function (event) {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $("input[type=checkbox].input-na").prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
});
```

It's getting into both areas with "if ($(this).prop("checked"))" which I've confirmed by putting in alerts, so it's the actual code to uncheck that isn't working.

Edit: Here is the mark-up:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">



    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[0].key" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[0].value.ResponseNum" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[0].value.Text" value="Self service gas, paid at the pump" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[0].value.IsNA" value="False" />

    <input type="checkbox" name="Questions[0].Responses" id="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_1" value="1" 

    />
    <label for="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_1">Self service gas, paid at the pump</label>



    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[1].key" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[1].value.ResponseNum" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[1].value.Text" value="Self service gas, paid inside at the kiosk or convenience store" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[1].value.IsNA" value="False" />

    <input type="checkbox" name="Questions[0].Responses" id="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_2" value="2" 

    />
    <label for="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_2">Self service gas, paid inside at the kiosk or convenience store</label>



    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[2].key" value="3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[2].value.ResponseNum" value="3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[2].value.Text" value="Full service provided by attendant" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[2].value.IsNA" value="False" />

    <input type="checkbox" name="Questions[0].Responses" id="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_3" value="3" 

    />
    <label for="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_3">Full service provided by attendant</label>



    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[3].key" value="4" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[3].value.ResponseNum" value="4" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[3].value.Text" value="Convenience store purchase (not including gas or diesel)" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[3].value.IsNA" value="False" />

    <input type="checkbox" name="Questions[0].Responses" id="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_4" value="4" 

    />
    <label for="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_4">Convenience store purchase (not including gas or diesel)</label>



    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[4].key" value="5" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[4].value.ResponseNum" value="5" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[4].value.Text" value="Car wash" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[4].value.IsNA" value="False" />

    <input type="checkbox" name="Questions[0].Responses" id="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_5" value="5" 

    />
    <label for="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_5">Car wash</label>



    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[5].key" value="6" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[5].value.ResponseNum" value="6" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[5].value.Text" value="Washrooms" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[5].value.IsNA" value="False" />

    <input type="checkbox" name="Questions[0].Responses" id="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_6" value="6" 

    />
    <label for="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_6">Washrooms</label>



    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[6].key" value="7" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[6].value.ResponseNum" value="7" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[6].value.Text" value="None of the above" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ResponseOptions[6].value.IsNA" value="True" />

    <input type="checkbox" name="Questions[0].Responses" id="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_7" value="7" 

                                                                                                        class = "input-na"

    />
    <label for="Question_040179122124101173157046112086076030096242133244_7">None of the above</label>
```

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/thtWr/

Comment: Work here: http://jsfiddle.net/p7TzU/. As you have not posted your HTML markup for the checkboxes I made them up and it works fine. Please post your mark-up or any solution working or not is purely speculative.

Comment: @BomberFan: It still seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/p7TzU/1/ with your markup as well as your current script. If is N/A checked, all others are unchecked, if any of the others are checked, N/A is unchecked. Can you create your own fiddle replicating your issue?

Comment: I've edited my actual mark-up to what it truly is. When I put it into fiddle, I get a weird group of characters in the result "});//]]> " and it's not working there.

Comment: I removed my answer as it did not seem to do anything better than what you had which works with your markup.  There is some unknown here, not this code.

Comment: @BomberFan: I copied your new markup into the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p7TzU/2/ and it still works. There is most likely something else causing your issue instead of your script. Check if you happen to have other event bindings on those checkboxes, i.e: clicked, etc.. which may interfere with your current script. Also, someting `Sushanth --` answer is hinting at, are you dynamically adding the checkboxes to the DOM? i.e: through an ajax call or appended throguh script or similar

Comment: My bad, I copied the <script> tag into the Javascript section of fiddle. Removing that makes it work. This is weird why it's not working for me with my actual page.

Comment: I've solved my issue. It turned out to be an issue with jquery mobile. I had to modify my code to do a refresh as follows: $("input[type=checkbox]").not(".input-na").prop("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");